# How to access Website from android application(android application->website->website's database(mssql db server))

Tags: android, sql-server-2008

I am developing an android application .in the application i simply have loaded the url for login and registration .The website i have loaded into the android application using webview is developed in .net(aspx).Now I am having doubt that this website will function same on android device as it functions on a desktop ? will it be able to retrieve the data from mysql offline server automatically,for login and registration page ?

The url of the webpage i have loaded in the webview is :

www.bizmlm.in/mlmsoftware/commonside/loginpage.aspx

If wat i asked above is not possible then please guide me to about how to develop a sqlite db for that website on the android device and the sync the sqlite db with the sql server eventually..please help its urgent for me :(

EDIT : 
Hello Everybody,

Now i am thinking to first connect my android application to the website and the to the database.I have googled it if i directly access the remote database server it will be on the risk to be hacked.So it is secure to first hit the website from android application and then connect to database.
I found a link for connecting android application to website and get response from there.

I also know the connection string used by website to access the databse but i am unable to figure out the correct string what should i pass in SOAP_ACTION,OPERATION_NAME,WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE and SOAP_ADDRESS.

see the link below it shows how we can connect android application to website and get response from there
http://java.dzone.com/articles/invoke-webservices-android

Now i want to do this
android application ->website->database

Comment: you can get login detail from server via making webservices.

Comment: i want to know that a website developed in .net will work in similar way on android phone as it use to work on laptop or pc ?

Comment: that does not depend on the programming language it depends on the page layout and on the style files. It works if the browser is compatible Im using a android device for some time and had never problems with layout. Size could also be a problem because the screen is much smaller.  Try it out using the device browser

Comment: SOAP_ACTION,OPERATION_NAME,WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE and SOAP_ADDRESS. can be read from the wsdl file  the easiest way to create a client is to use the generator I suggested earlier

Answer (score 0):

well im not sure if I understand you correctly 
a website should work like on any other  browsing capable device.
If you want to access a remote database a recommend you use SOAP (should not be a problem on a windows server)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP

In android you can use the ksoap2 libraries they work like a charm 
http://ksoap2.sourceforge.net/

this can generate a soap proxy for ksoap2 from a wsdl file
http://sourceforge.net/projects/ksoap2genstub/

edit:
you can also check if the browser is on a mobile device and thus change the layout

Comment: hi please explain me the procedure how to develop a webservice to access server

Comment: well Im a j2ee developer I ve learnt that in school but thats some time ago try this  http://www.jpreece.com/php/developing-soap-web-services-with-php-csharp/   or  google for soap windows tutorial